# Passing more than two properties in object

Tags: javascript, jquery

I made a jQuery plugin where one of the properties needing to be passed is a multi-dimensional object, each requiring *three* properties. Problem is, I don't know how to send more than two. I have provided an example to show the current effect and the needed effect:

What I currently do:

```
$.dialog({
    title: "Delete Comment", 
    text: "Are you sure you want to delete this comment?", 
    buttons: {
        "Yes": function() { /*some operation*/ }
    }
});
```

What I need to do:

```
$.dialog({
    title: "Delete Comment", 
    text: "Are you sure you want to delete this comment?", 
    buttons: {
        "Yes": function() { /*some operation*/ } : true
    }
});
```

In order to show it's a special type of button (internally, the plugin would do something with the third value).

How is this achievable?

Comment: What are you expecting that ': true' to do? I don't understand how that is supposed to fit in with what you need.

Comment: this looks like you're trying to add a new event handler to figure out if the button "Yes" was clicked.

Comment: Actually, it would be to determine if the button is to close the dialog after running the function or not. But I need to allow for multiple buttons, not just one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this case, "Yes" is not a property ... it is a key and the function is the value.  You need to add another key/value pair.  Try ...

```
buttons: {
    "Yes": function() { /*some operation*/ },
    "Special" : true
}
```

Then you can check to see if `Special` exists and has the value of true.

Comment: This is exactly what I needed. For some odd reason I thought those were two different properties. The idea, though, is to allow for multiple buttons, so I'm assuming that would be done like this? `[{text: "Yes", func: function() {/*some operation*/}, close: true}, {text: "No", func: function() {/*some operation*/}, close: false}]`

Answer (score 0):

You can put whatever operations before the closes.

```
    $.dialog({
    title: "Delete Comment",
    text: "Are you sure you want to delete this comment?",
    buttons: [{
        "Yes": function () {
            $(this).dialog("close");
        }
    }, {
        "No": function () {
            $(this).dialog("close");
        }
    }, {
        "Maybe": function () {
            $(this).dialog("close");
        }
    }]
});
```